# Jquery "Not Implemented" IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've recently updated my jquery to 1.8.0, and since doing this I've found a couple of errors on IE 8, when loading the page it works fine, although once clicking on say the "showreel" link up the top of my page, it returns an error saying "not implemented".

http://www.shannonhochkins.com/

I've go no idea what It's winging about saying it's not implemented though! Has anyone ran into this problem before?

[image]

Comment: I can't find a "showreel" link at the top of that page.  Remember we don't know your page.  Please be more specific about how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, The giant button at the top of the page that looks like a video that say's "2011 showreel" on it. Or any of the gallery items for that matter. Cheers

Comment: OK, I had tried that (I just didn't think that was a "link at the top of the page" - I thought that was a "big graphic in the middle of the page") and it worked fine for me in IE8 so I can't reproduce the issue.  Are you sure that you have Adobe Flash installed in IE8?

Comment: I don't think so, but I rarely use IE, I just wanted to make sure it's functional for the users of it, I've added an image above of what the error looks like when I click on the image, or any of the gallery items. But I don't understand why it works on all other browsers except IE. @jfriend00

Comment: also, **http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/** This is the plugin I'm using for the modal windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular error you are seeing is discussed here http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=7.  It sounds like it's an issue with using the dialog code in IE8 in standards mode.  There is a work-around suggested in that discussion thread - you'd have to see if that applies to your code.

Comment: Thankyou so much mate, after about an hour of playing, I got there in the end! There was around 10 different fixes on that page, turns out that it's just missing one simple ".support" flag in the plugin :(... but hey, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In your file gallery.js line 440 and line 448 you use $(body) - this should be $('body') or $("body"). This is maybe not the only error.

IE might be more strict about this than the other browsers (i am just guessing here).

Try you website on firefox with the plugin firebug and have a  look at the errors in the firebug console.

Comment: `$('body')` should be `$(document.body)` for max efficiency.